# Android Eclipse- Do I need a new Manifest file for each activity?

Tags: eclipse, android-activity, android

I have 1 manifest file set up right now that has this inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.treacheryofimages.www"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.treacheryofimages.www.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity2"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity3"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity4"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I want to create new buttons for my second activity page. So do I need to create a new manifest page for every activtity?

Comment: Please take a look here to grasp a general overview of android development. [Android first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't create a second manifest.  There is only one AndroidManifest.xml per project.  I don't really see the relation that you are making between the buttons in an activity and the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your activities in the manifest file and leave your layouts in the

> source/res/layout

folder, there you can use a layout file for each view for example

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) you can find the official Android documentation on how to structure your folders in your project.